# Analytic functions on $\mathbb{H}$ such that $f(i)=3i$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of analytic functions from the upper half plane to itself satisfying $f(i)=3i$. Find $\displaystyle \sup_{f\in \mathcal{F}} |f'(i)|=s$. Then either construct a function $f$ such that $|f'(i)|=s$ or construct a sequence of functions $f_i$ such that $\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty}|f'(i)|=s$.

My thoughts:

Since the [Cayley transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform#Conformal_map) maps $i$ to $0$ and $3i$ to $1/2$, I first consider functions from the unit disk to itself satisfying $f(0)=1/2$ (seems easier). If I compose this with an automorphism of the disk $T(z)=\frac{z-1/2}{1-z/2}$, then $T\circ f (0)=0$. By Schwarz lemma, $|(T\circ f)'(0)|\leq 1$.

By the chain rule, $|T'(f(0))||f'(0)|=|T'(1/2)||f'(0)|=\frac{4}{3}|f'(0)|\leq 1$, so that $|f'(0)| \leq 3/4$.

However, how do I know if this is really the supremum I can get from $f$? Is my approach correct?

Also, if this is indeed the supremum, then since $f$ is not a rotation, obviously we cannot get $f$ such that $|f'(0)|=3/4$, how do I construct the sequence $f_i$?

Comment: Interesting question!

Comment: Maybe I read incorrectly, but isn't it certainly possible that $T/circ f$ is a rotation?

Comment: Try $f(z) = -T(z).$